DM Command in Discord sends duplicates
I made a command to DM a specific user and then output a message that it has been successful in the same channel, but for no reason at all it sends 2 DM's and 2 success messages.
@bot.tree.command(name="dm", description="Send a DM to a user")
async def dm(interaction: discord.Interaction, target_user: str, message_to_send: str):
    if (interaction.channel.id != [channel id]):
        return

    target_user = int(target_user.removeprefix('<@').removesuffix('>'))

    if (sent_messages.get(target_user) is not True):
        await bot.get_user(target_user).send(message_to_send)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Message sent successfully to <@{target_user}>", ephemeral=False)
        sent_messages[target_user] = True
    else:
        return

I have even added a sent variable to indicate if the message is sent or not, even though it shouldn't be needed. I added print statements and they only activated once.

There might be another instance of your bot running. Check what programs are running on your pc
